# Severe degradation of insulation on newly-exposed ceiling fixture wires. How to proceed?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

https://imgur.com/a/erIn0vd

After removing fixture from ceiling:
[image]
[image]

I was hoping to install a ceiling fan where a light fixture is. Now that it has been opened, I will hire an electrician to install it. However, now I am concerned about putting the original fixture back in the meantime. The condition of the wiring is in the pics. The breaker controls a lot more than just the room the light is in, so I need to flip it back on.

Should I cap off the wires or put the fixture back in while waiting for the electrician?

House was built in 1933. Not K&T.

Comment: Some or a lot of electrical tape is required. It will depend if you can tape it enough to be safe. How far does the damage go, if lucky only where you can use the tape but taping might cause more damage further on into the ceiling. This is what AFCI breakers are for.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you use the old or the new fixture. The problem still exists. It could be just the ends that are disintegrating. If the wires are too short after clipping off, then you can extend them with a connector.

Comment: When you say, “not knob and tube”, what are you basing that on? (Because it looks like k+t from here…)

Comment: Yeah, I hate dealing with that stuff any more than I must... and while I have hung ceiling fans from ordinary boxes (secured with screws rather than nails) I really can't recommend that. This does look like it's going to be messy enough to be worth paying a pro to deal with it.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate cloth covered rubber insulation was also used back in the day for conduit (pipe&wire) jobs and in pre-thermoplastic BX cables

Comment: Maybe paint with plastidip?  Available only in the spray version in white, but you could try the liquid in yellow.  Black available in both.

Comment: Update: I went ahead and used heat shrink rubber tubes to cover the exposed wire where the insulation is falling apart. Then I capped both wires individully with wire nuts. This seems to be working fine while I wait on an electrician. I like the AFCI suggestion by @crip659, I am adding that to the electrician's scope of work for any old circuits left. This house is a mixed bag of new and old wiring. At least the breaker panel is new.

Answer (score 6):

That damage is typical of old cloth-covered rubber insulation (such as used with K&T and similar wiring methods) that has been overheated for long periods at light fixture outlets. You can attempt to slip some heat-shrink tubing over the old wires as far as you can. You might even be able to cover the wires past the box (where such deterioration usually ends) by loosening/removing clamps. Obviously, you do not want any sections of bare conducter contacting the metal box or fixture mounting hardware. Your electrician will at minimum have to remove that box to install a fan-rated one, and will likely be required to somehow new wiring to that location, a procedure that often entails ceiling/wall finish damage.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am NOT an electrician, just a DIY person. Here is my opinion:

1. It look to me as if the wires coming out of the ceiling have insulation that may fall apart even more than it already has with further movement/touch.  This is dangerous and needs to be evaluated and repaired (or replaced more likely) by a professional, as the insulation degradation may be present on other sections of the wiring inside the ceiling/walls.
2. Forget the old and new light fixtures for now -- do not try to replace or install anything. Call an electrician. Do not try to tape, bend, push anything.
3. Certainly it would help to make sure the light and dark wires are not touching each other. To do that without further damaging the insulation, I would get two thick/freezer quart or pint size ziploc bags and gently push the open end of one ziploc bag over each of the two wires, up as far as you can. Then, secure each bag's lower part (away from the ceiling hole) to the adjacent ceiling with a short piece of e.g. duct tape.

The idea is to have an insulator (ziploc bag plastic) ***very temporarily*** shielding the metal wires from touching each other or the metal fixture mount. The duct tape should not touch the wires, nor a part of the ziploc on top of a wire -- it's just there to keep the ziploc from falling off.

Once you have done that, have an electrician come within 24 hours to properly stabilize the situation. The electrician can then diagnose your issues and suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Except in extreme emergency situations, I would not recommend Ziploc (or similar) bags (very thin, easy to get tiny holes...), duct tape (which can have some metal in it) or anything other than UL/ETL-listed electrical tape. Multiple layers of white and black tape are the only proper solution until an electrician can rip it all out.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I believe any taping runs a serious risk of knocking/scraping off insulation up higher along the wires where it may be impractical for the OP to prevent shorting. I have now clarified that my heavy-duty ziploc bag idea would be only for 24 hours or so until an electrician can arrive. The duct tape is only to secure an empty corner of the ziploc to the flat adjacent ceiling -- it is likely to stick to that ceiling better than UL electrical tape.